# OnLocationChanged() Doesn't work in background

Tags: android, kotlin, gps, location, maps

I'm using the following code to get user's current location. When app is on foreground it's working perfectly however when i try to change location at emulator in background it doesn't give me the location. What can i do?

```
class BackgroundLocation:Service(),LocationListener {


override fun onBind(intent: Intent?) = null

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    val locationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    val locationListener = BackgroundLocation()
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,5000,10f,locationListener)

    return START_STICKY
}



override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
   println(location.toString())
}

override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {
    
}
override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {
    
}
override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String?, status: Int, extras: Bundle?) {
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are using a background service. It works when is running as and as soon as app goes in background, service stops.
To get continuous updated in background you need to update service to a foreground service.

ForegroundService.java

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
        createNotificationChannel();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
                .setContentText(input)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();
        startForeground(1, notification);
        //do heavy work on a background thread
        //stopSelf();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public void startService() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", "Foreground Service Example in Android");
    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
}
```

If you are running the app on android 10 and above you need to request Background location.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

You can read all about background location, it limitation and foreground service here - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services